# Clicking <input type="image" /> using WebDriver, InternetExplorerDriver

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer, webdriver

I am trying to click on the image input type using webdriver, but it's not working.
The html code:

```
<input type="image" onclick="validationAndSubmit('next'); return false;" alt="Continue" src="/subscriptions/versions2/commonlab/images/buttons/continue.gif" name="continue">
```

The code I am using to click is:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("continue")).click();
```

I could invoke the Javascript like below, but that is not my intent.

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("validationAndSubmit('next'); return false;");
```

I would like to simulate end user experience on IE as much as possible.

What should I do in order to click the image input?

thanks
Jenga

Comment: That works fine for me. Is there anything else on the page with name='continue'?

Comment: Yes, there was another element with same name. after renaming it works now